# C# remove an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

In my update function(which is called every frame), I do this:

```
 Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x , this.transform.position.y , Camera.main.transform.position.z);
```

So, the main camera follows my player. This means a new Vector3 object will be created in every single frame. Do I need to remove it manually? I heard that C# has a garbage collector but I am not so sure.

Comment: in particular `Vector3` is a **struct** so it is stored on the stack and destroyed mediately once the scope is left where this value type instance was created ;) just like a `int someInt = 3;` ;)

Comment: I would avoid using `Camera.main` in an `Update` method. It's bad for performance. Might be better to assign it to a field once and then use that field instead ([Source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right the c# has garbage collector. So you don't have to worry about that.